# Mongodb aggregate return data conditionally

Tags: database, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to return ONLY data records which email not exist in other collection with mongodb aggregation. Example:

LetterCollection:

```
[
  {
    "email": "some@email.com",
    "data": "someData"
  }, {
    "email": "some2@email.com",
    "data": "someData2"
  },
]
```

UserCollection:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1"
    "email": "some@email.com",
  }
]
```

Get all letters which user email not exist in users collection.
Expected result:

```
[{
  "email": "some2@email.com",
  "data": "someData2"
}]
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run an aggregate operation on the `letters` collection in which the pipeline first does a [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to the `users` collection, joined on the `email` field.

Documents returned from this pipeline stage contain an array field with the joined documents, so you would need a further [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) pipeline step to filter documents where this new field does not have any documents. This can be done by checking the length of the array field with [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) and filtering using the [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) expression with the [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) comparison operator.

The result can be further [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)ed to remove the new field in those documents that match to give the final desired output.

The above pipeline can be expressed as:

```
db.letters.aggregate([
    { '$lookup': {
        'from': 'users',
        'localField': 'email',
        'foreignField': 'email',
        'as': 'users'
    } },
    { '$match': { '$expr': { '$eq': [ { '$size': '$users' }, 0 ] }  } },
    { '$project': { 'users': 0 } }
])
```

Comment: $gt should be $lte but I like your idea

Comment: You are spot on, had misread the question initially but I've updated my answer with the correct conditional operator. In essence you just need [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) since empty arrays always have zero length